# Can't connect draggable to empty sortable when setting its height on start of drag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable and two empty sortable elements. By using `connectWithSortable`, I should be able to connect the draggable element to a sortable element.

However, when the draggable element is first dragged into a sortable element, it doesn't connect to it. Only on the second drag does it connect.

If I use CSS to give the sortable elements a height of 100px, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/cekwuyq1/

However, if the height of the sortable elements are set to 100px when the dragging starts (which I am doing), the problem occurs: https://jsfiddle.net/v9y0L2n1/

```js
$(".sortable").sortable();

$(".draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable', // Selector selects lists that have sortable class
  helper: 'clone',
  start: function(event, ui) {
    $(".sortable").css("height", "100px"); // setting height on start of drag
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p class="draggable">Drag me down</p>

<div>
  <p>Sortable 1</p>
  <div class="sortable"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Sortable 2</p>
  <div class="sortable"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding a `mousedown` event to the draggable element and setting the height of the sortable elements to 100px when this event is called.

This is instead of setting the height by using the `start` event on the draggable item.

Margins on the `p` elements were preventing the dragging from working seamlessly, so I set them to `0`.

I used the `stop` event on the draggable item to set the sortable element's height to `fit-content` to remove unnecessary space after the dragging has stopped.

```js
$(".sortable").sortable();

$(".draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable', // Selector selects lists that have sortable class
  helper: 'clone',
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(".sortable").css("height", "fit-content");
  }
});

$(".draggable")
  .mousedown(function() {
    $(".sortable").css("height", "100px");
  })
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p class="draggable">Drag me down</p>

<br>

<div>
  <p>Sortable 1</p>
  <div class="sortable"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <p>Sortable 2</p>
  <div class="sortable"></div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w84g5ce0/

Answer (score 0):

try to add 0 height when create draggable function

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable', // Selector selects lists that have sortable class
  helper: 'clone',
  create: function( event, ui ) {
   $(".sortable").css("height", '0px');
  },
  start: function(event, ui) {
  $(".sortable").css("height", '100px');
  }
});
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: if you change height  to "min-height" it should work fine

Comment: Tried that on both the `create` and `start` event but no luck

Comment: checkout [this](https://jsfiddle.net/moufeed/1ux59m7v/1/)